# Reduce an expression with Sqrt

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
r Cos[γ[t]] + 1/2 l Sqrt[1 - (r^2 Sin[γ[t]]^2)/l^2]
```

How can I ask *Mathematica* to write my expression without `l^2` in the denominator such as:

```
r Cos[γ[t]] + 1/2*Sqrt[l^2 - r^2 Sin[γ[t]]^2]
```

Sorry, if my question is very simple, but I have been unable to work out an answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
r Cos[γ[t]] + 1/2 l Sqrt[1 - (r^2 Sin[γ[t]]^2)/l^2]
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> {l^2 > 0, l > 0}]
```

Or:

```
r Cos[γ[t]] + 1/2 l Sqrt[1 - (r^2 Sin[γ[t]]^2)/l^2]
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> {Re[l] > 0, Im[l] == 0}]
```

But I am sure this is discussed in `Simplify` help page.

**EDIT**

As @BobHanlon pointed out `l>0` implies `l^2>0`, so one should write:

```
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> {l > 0}]
```

Comment: @Bendesarts You are welcome, but you might also accept it ;)